# Is there a way to create a permanent sidebar in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I've started building a website using Flutter Web, but have come to the issue of being unable to create a persistent sidebar.

Do you know if there is a way to do so, either by somehow making AppBar vertical down the side, or by making a permanent drawer, like the one available in [MDC Web](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/drawer/permanent)?

My original idea was to have a Scaffold with this sidebar persisting across Navigator route changes. I tried playing with nested Navigators, but those didn't help me achieve my desired effect.

Thank you very much for your help 
--Jakub

Comment: any solution yet?

Comment: Doesn't look like it yet @SagarChavada. I haven't explored it much recently, I'll have a look when I'm free if I can figure something out, I have much more experience under my belt now then I did when I first asked the question :)

Comment: No worry, I implemented it.

Comment: Could I ask how please?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
 @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SideLayout(),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 4,
                  child: //your child
              )])
      }
```

// Side layout file

```
class SideLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideLayout({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          color: Color(0xff404040),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 70),
              Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
              Text(
                'Build beautiful Apps',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,

                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this work with Navigation? What if you nested pages, in the sense that content has buttons that push another page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is this a perfect solution but you can try this

Use builder property on MaterialApp and return a scaffold with your drawer

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        builder: (BuildContext ctx, child) => Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(),
          body: child!,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      );
}
```

The actual problem here was Navigation, but you can overcome the problem by using Navigation 2.0 in flutter or you can also refer [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router)